# Too slow Image upload in Wordpress Media Library as image number increases

Tags: media, media-library, uploads

we are using Wordpress 4.4.2 and the Wordpress Media Library for media management. We have noticed that as media (images, not videos or audio) number increases, the upload process takes too long...and the time it takes is about the same for both ie 50 kB and 6 MB images! It is not a network problem, this has been verified. Does Wordpress Media Library use an indexing method that slows the process down when the image number is big? Can we change the media upload directory so as to have an empty one at intervals?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well when you upload image usually thumbnails are being created. Could it be that you have configured many custom image sizes?

Comment: Hi, thank you for our comment. We have set 150x150 size for that at Settings->Media (and have checked the option below: Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions). Does it have an effect?

Answer (score 3):

To anyone who faces the same issue, the problem was caused by WP Smush. Once we deactivated it, images were uploaded within seconds. We use nginx and gzip is doing the necessary compression anyway.

Kind Regards

Comment: Or you could just uncheck the option "Smush images on upload" and the plugin won't interfere at all in the uploading process and you still get to optimise your images using the Bulk Smush or Manually in Media Library